# Division Console output with a comma not rounded

Tags: c++, console-application

Is there a way for the console output to be a decimal number with a comma my output is always rounded and i can barely us it like this.

```
Int a = 90 ;
Int b = 7;
Int c = a/b;
```

This out puts 13 not the actual value.

Comment: Don't use `int`. Integer division is always rounded. Try to use a floating point type.

Comment: Please check any elementary C++ tutorial :) For your information there isn't bult-in type `Int` in C++, so it seems that you want to ask about `int` type division. The answer could be: store your result in some floating point type as `float` :)

Comment: An int division `90 / 7` makes 12 in C++, not 13. Are you sure it's C++?

Answer (score 1):

It is advice rewritten from my comment:

Please check any elementary C++ tutorial :) For your information there isn't bult-in type `Int` in C++, so it seems that you want to ask about `int` type division. The answer could be: store your result in some floating point type as `float` :)

You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

use `float` or `double` instead. `int` will never provide you with decimals.
Example:

```
float a=90,b=7;
float c = a/b;
printf("%.2lf",c);
```

The code avobe mentioned will write 2 decimals. If you want more, just change the 2 here `%.2lf` for your amount of decimals required.

Comment: You might want to be clear about the types of `a` and `b`,

Comment: Did you may be consider that some people writes automatically capital letter after a point?

Comment: The "%.2lf" specifier is for double and the `c` is a float.

Comment: @Lomezno No, not if it's C++ source code.